# How to merge/update duplicate records upon creation?

Tags: duplicate-management

We started to look into cleaning our data.

We are using Dupecatcher as the deduplication tool.

I am trying to figure a way, when a new lead (duplicate) is about to be created, it will update all current blank fields on the current lead, with new data from the form.

Does Dupecatcher suppport that?

Any other way to do it?

- I can use the alerts from DC, and manually merge the duplicates. Not looking for that.

Comment: The functionality you're asking about is not something DupeCatcher can do.  More importantly, blind-updates based on a record as 'thin' as a Lead is a dangerous piece of automation, in my opinion.  I would recommend looking into a more robust tool (CRMFusion has a great dedupe/merge tool).  But if that's not an option, then you're going to have to write a trigger.

Comment: I know it's dangerous, which is why I mentioned I want to update empty fields only.